# Seams visible on ceiling

Tags: ceiling

We recently had builders replace the ceiling of the main bedroom. When they left, the ceiling wasn’t yet painted, but now we've painted it, the seams are quite visible.

Is this normal or should I ask them to come back and fix it?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think this could end up just being 'opinion-based', however…

It's not a great job, but from what I can see of the door architrave & window beyond, that's an old build, Victorian perhaps, so your chances the joists were straight & level are much less.
If it was a new build, I'd get them back in. On a Victorian house… it's about what you'd expect, unless you go properly expensive & include laser-levelling/testing.

Comment: Thanks. The house is indeed Victorian. They did however add new joists to the ceiling next to the existing old ones that have sacked quite a bit so the ceiling should be set against the new joists.

Comment: Odds are that in a few weeks you'll stop noticing it, anyway.